# How much precious metals prices come from their use as investement vs practical use

Tags: investment, price, value

Some precious metal price come almost exclusively from their value as an investement, as gold, while some others like palladium or osmium have important uses in industries. But lately those metals also gained attention as a location of capital. Are there some estimations of how much of the price come from use as ivestement vs use in industry and others?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precious_metal